# Json Schema for Aspect Oriented Json files

Tags: json, jsonschema

So my json structure is aspect oriented, meaning that the json is structure in a way that each data is represented by a key and that key will define the structure of its content.

for example:

```
[
  {
    "nv": [{ "ln": 123 }]
  },

  {
    "metadata": [{ "name": "nodes" }, { "name": "edges" }]
  },
  {
    "nodes": [{ "@id": 1 }, { "@id": 2 }]
  },
  {
    "edges": [
      { "@id": 1, "nodeId": 1 },
      { "@id": 2, "nodeId": 2 }
    ]
  },
  {
    "status": [{ "success": true }]
  }
]
```

As shown 3 objects (nv, metadata, status) and based on the `name` inside of the metadata there will be objects inside the json file.

I tried something like this:

```
{
  "type": "array",
  "items": [
    {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "nv": { "type": "array", "items": { "$ref": "#definitions/nv" } }
      },
      "required": ["nv"]
    },
    {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "metaData": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": { "$ref": "#definitions/metadata" }
        }
      },
      "required": ["metaData"]
    },
    {
      "anyOf": [
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "nodes": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": { "$ref": "#definitions/nodes" }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "edges": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": { "$ref": "#definitions/edges" }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "edgeAttribute": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": { "$ref": "#definitions/edgeAttribute" }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "nodeAttribute": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": { "$ref": "#definitions/nodeAttribute" }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },

    {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "status": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": { "$ref": "#definitions/status" }
        }
      },
      "required": ["status"]
    }
  ],

  "definitions": {
    "status": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "success": { "type": "boolean" }
      }
      "etc..."
    }
  }
}
```

but then if I define an empty array it will be accepted, also it is being accepted if the array only contains one of the 3 required objects.

So is there a way to validate against something like the example using json-schemas?

The real scenario may have more than just 2 objects inside of the metadata that's why I did not use `if -> then -> else` conditions. if the solution is by using them then please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure of the data makes this a rough one, but there are a few patterns you can use to get the behavior you want. Let's take them one at a time.

**Declare an array that can contain any of a number of objects**

Generally people use `oneOf` for this, but I don't recommend that because it can have poor performance and incomprehensible error messages. Usually that means `if`/`then`, but in this case you can get good results by defining your items as a single object that only allows one property at a time in each object.

```json
{
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "nv": { "$ref": "#/definitions/nv" },
      "metadata": { "$ref": "#/definitions/metadata" },
      "status": { "$ref": "#/definitions/status" },
      "nodes": { "$ref": "#/definitions/nodes" },
      "edges": { "$ref": "#/definitions/edges" }
    },
    "minProperties": 1,
    "maxProperties": 1
  }
}
```

**Edit**: Previously, I recommended `dependencies`, but then realized that this is better.

**Assert that the array contains a required object**

To do this, you need to assert that the array `contains` an object that has a `required` property.

```json
{ "contains": { "type": "object", "required": ["nv"] } }
```

You'll have to combine this pattern in `allOf` to express additional required items.

```json
{
  "allOf": [
    { "contains": { "type": "object", "required": ["nv"] } },
    { "contains": { "type": "object", "required": ["metadata"] } },
    { "contains": { "type": "object", "required": ["status"] } }
  ]
}
```

**Conditionally assert that the array contains a required object**

The tricky part here is getting all the nested `contains` and `properties` in the `if` to be able to assert that the "name" is a certain value. The `then` just uses the same pattern we used above to assert than an object is required in the array.

```json
{
  "if": {
    "type": "array",
    "contains": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "metadata": {
          "type": "array",
          "contains": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "name": { "const": "nodes" }
            },
            "required": ["name"]
          }
        }
      },
      "required": ["metadata"]
    }
  },
  "then": { "contains": { "type": "object", "required": ["nodes"] } }
}
```

The above example shows the "nodes" object being conditionally required. You'll need to repeat this pattern for the "edges" object and combine them with `allOf`. I suggest making use of `definitions` to help make this readable.

```json
{
  "allOf": [
    { "$ref": "#/definitions/if-metadata-has-nodes-then-require-nodes-object" },
    { "$ref": "#/definitions/if-metadata-has-edges-then-require-edges-object" }
  ]
}
```

Comment: when defining the first parts of the schema https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/RdyN5BE2 if the array only has for example `nv` then it throws an error on the object it self saying that `metadata is missing on the property` instead of throwing it on the array itself

Comment: I was trying the first part of the solution and then i am going to check for the `Conditionally assert that the array contains a required object` part but can you help me in the first part

Comment: The error _is_ on the array. That error is saying that `#/allOf/1` and a `#/allOf/2` are failing on the array. The indented errors are showing why those sub-schemas failed. The errors are a little awkward, but I don't think there's a better way.

Comment: Okk, so is there a way to get specific or more detailed errors? because i will be using this schema in `ajv` and then in `monaco-editor`, and when testing it on monaco-editor play ground it shows errors that are not understandable by normal users. Do you recommend anything?

Comment: In ajv, you could try https://www.npmjs.com/package/ajv-errors to improve error messages. I haven't used it, so I don't know how well it might solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest moving each of your "types" into a `$defs` to be referenced.

```json
{
  "$defs": {
    "nvObj": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "nv": { "type": "array", "items": { "$ref": "#/$defs/nv" } }
      },
      "required": ["nv"]
    },
    ...  // other defitions
  }
}
```

(I've updated the `$ref` to use `$defs` instead of `definitions` as this is the new keyword since draft 7.)

Then you can put many references into a `oneOf`.

```json
{
  "$defs": {
    ... // from above
  },
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "oneOf": [
      { "$ref": "#/$defs/nvObj" },
      ... // all of the other object definitions
    ]
  }
}
```

You're right to avoid `if`/`then`/`else` for this case.  `oneOf` is the best bet here.

Comment: okk so i created a full schema in [here](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/zDqoPqmC) but the problem is that now the schema only validates if each object contains the 3 main types (nv, metadata, status) but in my use case i want that each type is a separate object

Comment: I've updated your example [here](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/zDqoPqmC).  I've needed to ensure that all of the `nvObj`-like definitions have `required`, but it was missing on some of them.

Comment: Oh! and also your `items` keyword was still an array form.  If you just have it as a single schema (as I show above), that schema must validate _all_ of the items.  Having an array form of `items` will validate each item index-for-index.

Comment: @gregsdennis just want to ask you is it possible to require that the first and the last item of the array are of a specific types and the in between are 'anyOf' a set of subschemas?

Comment: You can do the first item, but there's not a way to do the last item.  It has been [brought up](https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues/1060), though.  `prefixItems` works with `items` to do this.  In drafts before 2020-12, this would be `items` and `additionalItems`, respectively.